# REST API error - Illegal string offset 'context' in class-wp-rest-request.php while reading response header from upstream

Tags: custom-post-types, rest-api

This error appears when using the API REST doing a POST call to publish a new post (it's a custom post type).
The thing is that a draft post is created at the same time.

> Illegal string offset `context` in
> `/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-request.php` on line 456" while
> reading response header from upstream

If I do a POST call to publish a new post, it works perfect.

As well as a possible answer (which I think is a bit difficult), I want to learn how can I debug this to try to fix it.

Thanks in advance